# Swift 3: Cannot call value of non function type 'Bundle'

Tags: ios, swift3

Currently I am working on one of my project which was in swift2 and I am converting to swift 3. I got below error:

> Cannot call value of non function type 'Bundle'

at

```
let modelURL = Bundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("VerseApp", withExtension: "momd")!
```

Following is code:

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
  let modelURL = Bundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("VerseApp", withExtension: "momd")!
   print(modelURL)
   return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()
```

Comment: You getting error in this line?
let modelURL = Bundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("VerseApp", withExtension: "momd")!

Comment: Easy hint to help yourself: ⌘-click on the symbol (`Bundle`) and look up the method in the header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax is bit changed in Swift 3, it is `main` not `mainBundle()` and  `URLForResource` is changed to [`url(forResource:withExtension:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1411540-url) also the init of `NSManagedObjectModel` is changed to [`init?(contentsOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectmodel/1506225-init) from `init?(contentsOfURL:)`

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "VerseApp", withExtension: "momd")!
    print(modelURL)
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()
```

Comment: @bittu Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 3):

In swift 3 the most of api was renamed

Just try this line instead of your

```
 Bundle.main.url(forResource: "VerseApp", withExtension: "momd")
```

Also take a look to this articles, it will help you to learn changes since 2 version.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/135655/whats-new-swift-3
https://www.raywenderlich.com/156352/whats-new-in-swift-3-1

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "VerseApp", withExtension: "momd")!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let modelURL = Bundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("VerseApp", withExtension: "momd")!
```

Replace above line with this

```
let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "VerseApp", withExtension: "momd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead your:

```
var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
            let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "VerseApp", withExtension: "momd")!
            print(modelURL)
            return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
        }()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this -

```
let bundleUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "VerseApp", withExtension: "momd")!
```